# htaccess with multiple levels

Tags: .htaccess

I saw htaccess guides here but i think im doing it wrong. Here's my sample code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ page.php?p=$1&c=$2&gc=$3
```

The issue i am facing here is, there are 3 levels of page that have links to each level. I usually get "Not Found" if i am going to the first parameter, even the 2nd parameter. It shows correct only the 3rd parameter.

What i would like to know here is, how can i configure my htaccess to get the certain page without having the link ended-up to "Not Found".

Comment: What do breadcrumbs have to do with your .htaccess? What is the problem you are facing? Please edit your question and edit in a clear problem description.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Im not good in technical grammar, but i hope the question i've changed suit everyone's understanding when it comes to "Not Found" from HTACCESS code errors.

Oh, I forgot, i have links at my breadcrumbs that reflects the levels of my pages where the "NOT FOUND" occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule only matches if the path contains 3 parts. You need to create 2 more rules for the case where the path contains 2 parts and where the path contains 1 part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ page.php?p=$1&c=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I also advice to use the `[L]` flag on the rule you already have. This will speed up things a little bit and might also prevent weird behaviour, especially when you are using redirects.